# disable javascript alerts in dreamweaver CS4

Tags: dreamweaver, alerts

every time I do not complete a portion of javascript code, it always appears alert messages in Dreamwaver and is really annoying. How do I disable these alerts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in Dreamweaver CS6, this was bugging the heck out of me too.

It's called the "Syntax Error Alerts in Info Bar".

In the "View" menu under "Code View Options" you can turn this off.

Comment: in my dreamweaver cc 2015 its disabled(grayed out)

Answer (score 1):

View > Live View Options > Disable JavaScript